# How to set the background color of RectangleF c#?

Tags: c#, gdi+

How to set the background color of a rectangle drawn using rectangleF object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RectangleF` **is just a structure** to store some info of a rectangle measured in `float`. `GDI+` uses this structure to draw, fill the colorful stuff into it. We have to use the `Graphics` object to fill it. Here is the example code for you:

```
//Fill on a Bitmap
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(someBitmap);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, yourRectangleF);
```

In some `Paint` event handler, we can get the `Graphics` object via the passed-in argument `e`, normally of type `PaintEventArgs`, like this:

```
//Fill on a Form
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, yourRectangleF);
}
```